# How can I make one edge sharp but the other round with subdivision on?

Tags: modeling, edges, subdivision-surface

I am following Guru's tutorial on how to make an anvil but I wouuld like to go further than him and make the bottom edge round and the top sharp like in the image.
But i've tried a bunch of different things and the topology always ends messed up and subdiv as well.
Thanks for the answers!

[image: anvil]

Comment: you can select these edges and bevel (Ctrl B)

Comment: I just tried but then I can't loopcut the top edge to make it sharp

Comment: what do you mean? could you please show a picture, and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: because of the subdiv I need to make loop cuts in order to have sharp edges in all the parts of my mesh except the part that is round but then I end up with faces that only have 3 vertices and can't bevel the edges that I need. https://pasteall.org/blend/ce9652dd067241028cbe38a5bb513292
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: is it not what you want? https://zupimages.net/up/21/40/dkxn.jpg

Comment: that's it ! but I would also like the bottom to be like this : https://zupimages.net/up/21/40/kxm3.jpg

Comment: the problem is when I do this edge loop it creates a square which I don't want, except for the top of the anvil. It's quite tricky to explain, but I joined the discord maybe I can ask for help on it, thanks for the invite btw !

Comment: ok see you in the Discord then  ;)